# Telegram Bot Login via PHP MadelineProto

Tags: php, api, bots, telegram, chatbot

I have a private Telegram Channel. My bot is added to this Channel as admin.

I have a Webservice (PHP) which receives event. I want to tell my bot to kick a user from the Channel on a specific event - without any user interaction.

I am using MadelineProto library, but it always/sometimes asks for a api_id/api_hash, which I need to enter manually.

How can I specify those values (settings?) so that I do not need any user interaction?

```
if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$settings = [
    'app_info' => [
        'api_id' => 'xxxxxx',
        'api_hash' => 'xxxxxxx'
    ]
];

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session');
$MadelineProto->updateSettings($settings);

$auth = $MadelineProto->botLogin($BOT_TOKEN);

//Get Channel/User, kick user logic, this works, but I need to enter app_id/app_hash manually.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work this way:

```
        $settings['app_info']['api_id']=xxx;
        $settings['app_info']['api_hash']='xxx';

        $MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session', $settings);
```